# Использование в одном проекте методов класса из другого

Tags: c#, ооп, классы

Имеется solution, в котором созданы два проекта. В одном из них создан класс с методами. Этот проект подключен к другому по ссылке.

Как мне передать методы класса из первого проекта во второй?

Вот так выглядит структура решения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сделать их публичными

Comment: Суть в том, что класс не видно в проекте к которому подключен проект с классом, поэтому я не могу обращаться к методам, так как не могу создать о объект.

Comment: @Nicholas Пора показать код. Даже как-то стыжусь спрашивать - `namespace` в `using` написали? Target framework у обоих проектов одинаковая?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы хотите использовать методы **ИЗ** какого-либо класса из другой сборки, то нужно, чтобы эти методы были публичные в этом классе (можно сделать их `protected` и создать наследника). Класс тоже должен быть публичным (или `protected` и делать наследника).
Вообще можно сделать всё `internal` и добавить `InternalsVisibleTo` на сборку, где хотите использовать `internal` методы, всё на ваше усмотрение.

Пример кода, где **Assembly 1**, подключено в **Assembly 2**

```
// Assembly 1
public class Class1 {
    public void Method1() { }
}

// Assembly 2
new Class1().Method1();
```

**Обновление**

Класс должен быть в определенном пространстве имен, попробуйте найти строчку в файле `ArrayClass.cs`, которая содержит в себе слово **namespace**. На этой же строке, после слова *namespace* указано имя вашего пространства, попробуйте вставить его непосредственно перед классом, например, если в моем примере у `Class1` неймспейс будет `Assembly1`, то из второй сборки можно обратиться к нему так: `Assembly1.Class1` (а создать так: `new Assembly1.Class1()`)

**Обновление 2**

Я заметил немного странную вещь, возможно это совпадение, но всё же, осмелюсь предположить, что у вас и первый и второй проекты являются WinForms приложениями. Хотя, по вашему вопросу, следовало ожидать, что WindowsFormsApplication1 будет как библиотека классов (.dll), но всё же, .exe файлы тоже можно добавлять в ссылки к другим проектам. Убедитесь, что ссылка точно присутствует, потому что добавление еще одного проекта в решение - недостаточно. На всякий случай: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/wkze6zky(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: http://img-host.org.ua/images/mmmmmm.png Вот так выглядит структура решения, мне нужно передать методы из класса ArrayClass ко второму проекту, все что я могу передать, то только методы из класса Form1

Comment: @Nicholas Может покажете содержимое ArrayClass.cs (или он секретный?) и как Вы его используете? Рекомендуется это сделать путем редактирования вопроса.

Comment: Там обычные методы сортировки (слиянием, пузырем, вставкой). А использую я их для сравнения ефективносни каждого метода, в первом проекте сравнивается сортировки вставкой и пузырем, а во втором проекте нужно реализовать сравнения сортировки вставкой и слиянием.

Comment: @Nicholas А зачем Вы нам все это рассказываете? Вам надо сделать, чтобы код `namespace A { public class B { public int GetValue() { return 123; } } }` и `int a = new A.B().GetValue();` заработал.

Answer (score 1):

Никак, вы можете вынести этот класс в третий проект и передать его в зависимости первому и второму.

Но вы не можете получить доступ к коду в зависимом классе.

**Обновление**

Все просто, как я понял у автора Проект1 ссылается на Проект2, таким образом классы Проекта2 доступны в Проекте1, но не наоборот. В Проекте2 не будет доступа к классам Проекта1 и он не может ссылаться на Проект1 так как будет циклическая зависимость. В общем два проекта не могут ссылаться друг на друга, только один на другой. Если вы хотите, чтобы какой-то класс из Проекта1 (при условии что он ссылается на Проект2) был доступен в Проекте2, то так сделать не получится, но можно сделать Проект3 на который будут ссылаться Проект1 и Проект2 и вынести в него тот класс, который должен быть общим.

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить класс с кодом (файл *.cs) в решение. А в обоих проектах сделать на него ссылку:

> Меню проекта: Добавить -> Существующий элемент -> Выбираем файл -> нажимаем стрелочку рядом с кнопкой добавить -> Добавить как связь